# Why aren't my Characteristic appearing in BLE advertisement Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to advertise some characteristics from an iPhone acting as a peripheral, but although the service seems to contain the characteristics they don't show up when you look at it with a BLE scanner, the service works fine and displays the localNameKey.

thanks

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate{

var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!
let myCustomServiceUUID: CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "B5893BC9-63AB-42A5-BB33-EEAE686BED1D")
let myCustomCharacteristic: CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "9BA41369-C5B7-456B-B4E3-BB0A8DFF3A95")
let myCustomCharacteristic2: CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "9BA41369-C5B7-456B-B4E3-BB0A8DFF3A85")
var myService: CBMutableService!
var myCharacteristics: CBMutableCharacteristic!
var myCharacteristics2: CBMutableCharacteristic!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    myService = CBMutableService(type: myCustomServiceUUID, primary: true)

    myCharacteristics = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: myCustomCharacteristic, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties.Broadcast, value: nil, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.Readable)
    myCharacteristics2 = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: myCustomCharacteristic2, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties.Broadcast, value: nil, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.Readable)

    myService.characteristics = [myCharacteristics, myCharacteristics2]
    peripheralManager.addService(myService)



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn {
        let dataTobeAdvetised :[String: AnyObject!] = [CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [myService.UUID], CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: "MY Device"]
        self.peripheralManager.startAdvertising(dataTobeAdvetised)
        print(myService)
        print("It should be working!........")


    } else if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOff {
        self.peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
    }
}



}
```

Comment: I believe the reason its not advertising the characteristics is because its failing to add the service to the GATT database, the didAddService function returns an error, the error is "0" unknown error, I wondered if it might be because it haven't requested the users permission to access coreBluetooth, i can't find how to do it, CBperipheralManager has no request authorisation functions.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't permitted to use `CBCharacteristic.broadcast` property value.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBCharacteristicProperties) -

> - **CBCharacteristicPropertyBroadcast**
>
> The characteristic’s value can be broadcast using a characteristic
>   configuration descriptor.
>
> This property is not allowed for local characteristics published via
>   the addService: method of the CBPeripheralManager class. This means
>   that you cannot use this property when you initialize a new
>   CBMutableCharacteristic object via the
>   initWithType:properties:value:permissions: method of the
>   CBMutableCharacteristic class.

You should use some combination of `CBCharacteristicPropertyRead`, `CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse` and `CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite` depending on your requirements.

Comment: hi, i was added service and characteristic. But service was empty(connect by nrfConnect app in android - iOS: peripheral & android:central).  service was empty. So which mistake i made in code?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but hopefully this will help somebody else. I was struggling with the same issue, but for me there was no didAddService callback. Turns out GATT initialisation should be after the peripheral state has changed to PoweredOn.

```
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn {
        //Do initialisation and then start advertising.
    }
}
```